# Getting %3F on URLs

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and I'm trying to get all *links* from a website. This is my script:

```
include('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://example.com/urls/');

// find all a tags
foreach($html->find('a') as $e)
    echo $e->href . "\n";
```

What I'm getting is the full list of *urls* but some of them end with a **%3F** where there sould be a string. Something like:

```
http://example.com/urls/%3F
```

Instead of:

```
http://example.com/urls/foo
```

I've done some research and it seems the fix needs to be done on the *Apache server* bu tI don't have access to it, is there anything I could do to fix it?

Comment: %3F is just the URL encoded version of **?** ... I doubt this is something that needs any *"fixing"* in Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just decode incoming url like this :

```
echo urldecode($e->href)."\n";
```

It will give the decoded url for string.